# Sum of Angles in a Triangle.

Tags: geometry, triangles

Can anyone please explain how to form a better idea in understanding sum of measures of angles in a triangle is $180^\circ$ ?

Comment: Maybe [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/104260/rotations-and-the-parallel-postulate)

Comment: if a ray stand on a line then the sum of the adjactent angels so formed is 180degree

Answer (score 15, accepted):

How about this?

Here, we use the linear pair axioms (version 1, below) and the fact that the alternate interior angles of  are equal when a parallel line is intersected by a transveral.

**Linear Pair Axioms:**

1. If a ray stands on line, then the sum of two adjacent angles so formed is $180^\circ$.
2. If the sum of two adjacent angles is $180^\circ$, then the non-common arms of the angles form a line.

[image: angsumtriangle]

P.S.: I think these are more intuitive facts in geometry.

Comment: +1 Elementary result, of course, but a very nice explanation indeed