# Proofs from the "Ugly Book"

Tags: proof-writing, philosophy

There is a famous saying in mathematics from Paul Erdős: "You don't have to believe in God, but you should believe in The Book." "The Book" is an imaginary book in which God had written down the best and most elegant proofs for mathematical theorems.

If there is a book written down by God, why not a book from the Devil? I mean, a book with the most ugly proofs, but yet the best ones we have as accepted proofs. I don't mean to make a horrible proof on purpose, but sometimes ugly proofs is all you have.

I wish if you could share some theorem from the Ugly Book, some theorem proved by a real ugly proof (and yet the only one that there is). I'm asking this not for fun only, but I'm curious about how ugly proofs can be.

Comment: **First** proofs of a result are frequently ugly.

Comment: Perhaps the four-color theorem qualifies?

Comment: The devil can be quite elegant at times.

Comment: classification of finite simple groups ?

Comment: I would say Carleson's theorem on a.e. convergence of Fourier series doesn't have an elegant proof yet.

Comment: Mariano's proof here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/269833/whats-a-proof-that-the-angles-of-a-triangle-add-up-to-180 that angles of all triangles in the plane sum 180º looks like a perfect example of a "sledgehammer to crack a nut" and I think it could belong there. I wouldn't say it's an ugly proof though, I actually liked it when I saw it.

Comment: Yes, to prove some simple as it is I would say that this proof is ugly enough!

Comment: I like Mariano's sledgehammer proof.  Also, I understood the question as asking not just for ugly proofs but for ugly proofs that are the *only* available proofs of some results.

Comment: This question is insanely subjective. Cf. Michael Greinecker's answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Beauty is quite subjective. One may prove something in 2 lines using the newly developed supersymmetric coffee spaces, and that may be cool to some. Suppose you have another proof of the same result that uses only some primitive set of axioms. This proof may potentially be 1000 pages long, but it will be more beautiful to some (for example me), as it is a demonstration of the fact that all that mind blogging complexity is actually the result of addition, multiplication, etc, and some first order logic.

Answer (score 5):

**There exists irrational numbers $x$ and $y$ such that $x^y$ is rational.**

**Proof:** If $\sqrt{2}^\sqrt{2}$ is rational, we can take $x=y=\sqrt{2}$. If $\sqrt{2}^\sqrt{2}$ is irrational, we take $x=\sqrt{2}^\sqrt{2}$ and $y=\sqrt{2}$.

---

The proof is based on a case distinction in which only one case is true, without telling us which one. The proof is discused at [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructive_proof) wikipedia page.

Comment: I always thought that this proof was beautiful, do you think its ugly ?

Comment: @Amr Yes, a proof that acknowledges ignorance so fully and leaves so many open questions makes me feel empty inside.

Comment: I think you have a very different notion of proof beauty from mine.

Comment: This proof looks fine to me.

Comment: Anyway, you can just take $f(x) = \sqrt{2}^x$ and get the result by continuity. This proof is interesting because it shows how little you need to know to establish the result; I've never thought it was ugly.

Comment: @EricTressler How does your continuity argument work?

Comment: I’d say that it’s beautiful, delightfully clever, and utterly uninformative.

Comment: I upvoted both Michael Greinecker's answer and @Amr's comment.