# Sum of angles of Triangle greater than 180

Tags: geometry

Can we prove that sum of angles of triangle is greater than 180.
  -assumptions are allowed.
If you have any suggestion please let me know

Comment: I am not sure this is the right place for this question. Anyway: ON A SPHERE just take 2 non-coincident points on the equator and consider one of the poles: the sum of the angles is certainly greater tha 180°. This will never work in a flat space (sum=180) or on a hyperbolic surface (sum <180)

Comment: This is not a triangle in the classical sense. The triangle is a planar figure and the angle are taken between the lines joining the vortices, not the curves...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may depend on your definition of *triangle*, but at least in Euclidian geometry the sum of interior angles of a triangle (three points connected by straight lines) is always 180°.

See also [Sum of Angles in a Triangle.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/104377/sum-of-angles-in-a-triangle)